# Leaflet map double marker issue

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, ionic3, openstreetmap

I am building an ionic3 app and using leaflet for the map functions. However i encountered a strange behavior. After page load the location is automaticly fetched if GPS is turned on. After this for a more precise location the given marker can be moved. After this if i click on the "Locate me" button then the marker is removed but after the location if fetched again i get two markers added to my current location. Its like the marker got removed from the map but not from the markers array. Every time i click "Locate me" i get an extra marker so after the second click i have 3 markers in total and on.

The "Locate me" button calls the locate() function.

Here is the code that i am using:

```
presentAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'GPS hiba',
      subTitle: 'Kérem kapcsolja be a GPS vevőt a helyzete meghatározásához!',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Ok',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {

          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.getMap();
  }

  getMap() {
    this.map = leaflet.map("map");
    leaflet.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attributions: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
      minZoom: 6
    }).addTo(this.map);

    this.map.bounds = [];

    this.map.fitBounds([
      [45.636684, 16.030223],
      [48.708459, 22.863228]
    ]);

    this.map.setMaxBounds([
      [45.636684, 16.030223],
      [48.708459, 22.863228]
    ]);

    this.locate();
  }

  locate() {
    this.map.locate({
      setView: true,
      maxZoom: 10,
      enableHighAccuracy: true
    });

    let marker;

    this.map.on('locationfound', (e) => {

      if (marker && this.map.hasLayer(marker)) {
        this.map.removeLayer(marker);
      }

      let lat = e.latitude;
      let lng = e.longitude;

      marker = new leaflet.marker([e.latitude, e.longitude], {draggable: 'true'});

      marker.on('dragend', function (event) {
        marker = event.target;
        let position = marker.getLatLng();

        lat = position.lat;
        lng = position.lng;

        marker.setLatLng(new leaflet.LatLng(position.lat, position.lng), {draggable: 'true'});
      });
      this.map.addLayer(marker);
    });

    this.map.on('locationerror', (err) => {
      this.presentAlert();
    })
  }
```

Every help will be much appreaciated.
Regards,
Trix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `marker` variable is scoped *inside* your `locate` method.

Therefore, a new one is created every time you call that method.

Not sure how you are able to remove it with the provided code...

Should you want to have only one location marker at a time, you could for example use an instance property instead: `this.marker`

It would be scoped to your instance, and the same reference re-used every time you call `locate`.

Comment: Yep that was the original ideea i have started off but didnt work back then. Now magicly works, interesting :) Thanks for the help. Cheers !